# Deviation of random effect stuck at 0 for underdispserd poisson data

Tags: r, lme4, poisson

I recently found a rather unexpected behavior of glmer for underdispersed data: the number of eggs laid in 4 nestboxes placed in 53 forest plots. The standard deviation estimates get stuck at 0 even if there are quite some between-group variation also the residual standard deviation is not reported.

Here is some simulated data close to the actual data distribution:

```r
set.seed(20180124)
library(lme4) #v1.1-13

plot_int <- rnorm(53,exp(2),1)
datt <- data.frame(id_plot = rep(1:53,each=5))
datt$Egg <- ceiling(rnorm(265,plot_int[datt$id_plot],0.1))

(glmer(Egg ~ 1 + (1 | id_plot),datt,family="poisson"))

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: Egg ~ 1 + (1 | id_plot)
   Data: datt

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1085.9   1093.1   -541.0   1081.9      263 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.10153 -0.40068 -0.05025  0.30018  0.65060 

Random effects:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id_plot (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 265, groups:  id_plot, 53

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  2.09721    0.02153   97.42   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Is this a desirable behavior from glmer? Would there be some way to detect that during model fitting leading to a warning message?

Running it via lmer gives proper estimation of both the residual and the between-group variance. While trying glmer.nb gives convergence warnings and the dispersion parameter which should be negative (I guess) hits super large values. So what would be the best way to model such data, especially if the normal approximation is not an option (low means ...)?

Comment: You could use `library(MCMCglmm); 
datt$id_plot <- factor(datt$id_plot); 
fit <- MCMCglmm(Egg ~ 1, ~ id_plot, family = "poisson", data = datt); 
summary(fit)`. It reports (with default priors) a very similar fixed effect as `glmer` and a very small random intercept. You are posing a very difficult problem to `glmer` and a zero random effect variance is not that wrong an answer here.

Comment: @Roland: yes that would be an option even if I'd like to avoid going into Bayesian grounds on this one.